# generate barcodes when a certain quantity is inputted in a textbox,

Tags: java, ms-word

i need to generate barcodes when a certain quantity is inputted in a textbox.but can seem to work with this codes that i made. any help would be appreciated.

```
import com.aspose.barcode.BarCodeBuilder;
import com.aspose.barcode.Symbology;
import com.aspose.words.Document;
import com.aspose.words.DocumentBuilder; 

   JButton btnCreate = new JButton("Create Barcode");
            btnCreate.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                    String strBaseFolder = "C:\\users\\ronjonathan\\desktop\\barcode\\";
                    try

                    {

                        // Generate barcode image
                        BarCodeBuilder builder = new BarCodeBuilder();
                        builder.setSymbologyType(Symbology.Code128);
                        for(int i = 1;i <= Integer.parseInt(txtBarcode.getText()); i++){

                        builder.setCodeText(Integer.toString(i));
                        String strBarCodeImageSave = "img.jpg"+ i;
                        builder.save(strBaseFolder + strBarCodeImageSave);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every time you run this code you write over the same file "img.jpg". Try changing

```
String strBarCodeImageSave = "img.jpg";
```

to

```
String strBarCodeImageSave = txtBarcode.getText() + ".jpg";
```